# Is there a limit on number of manufacturer options in Magento 2.1?

Tags: magento, magento2

I am running Magento 2.1 for my ecommerce store. I am adding options to Manufacturer attribute, but I am not able to add more than 59. After that when I add more options, I get success message but the new option is not added. Have someone faced this before? How do I resolve this?

Ashok

Comment: option_id in the table eav_attribute_option is int(10) so not limited to 59 entries but all the options are using this table. That means that you cannot have more than 9 999 999 999 options. I believe that it is not a problem. Is the option in the db and not displayed in front or not in db.

Answer (score 1):

Its probably related to the PHP directive "max_input_vars" try to increase it in your php.ini